# CSS Firefox Issue, button clickable only in half

Tags: css, firefox

Why when looking this button in order overview you can click only on half of it in Firefox(in other browsers its working fine).

Sorry, I don't know how to replicate the issue, but link is here (but you have to first add to cart something):
http://ilovedesign.sk/kosik

[image: button]

Comment: You problem style is this one: `span#confirmbtn { left: -50%; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this style:

`span#confirmbtn { left: -50%; }`

And then add this one:

`#confirmbtn_button { transform: translateX(-50%); }`